# JsonConvert.Deserialize appends to default property values. How to prevent this?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, properties, default-value

I have a .json config file in which I store application settings which are deserialized when the app starts.

Example:

```
{
    "MyProperty1": "MyValue1",
    "MyProperty2": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

The object to which the JSON is deserialized is:

```
public class Config{
    public string MyProperty1{ get; set; }
    public List<int> MyProperty2{ get; set; } = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
}
```

The problem I am having is that, when the JSON for the property `MyProperty2` is deserialized, it appends the values 1, 2, 3 to the default property values 4, 5, 6 and the result is that MyProperty2 = 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3

I'd like `MyProperty2` to DEFAULT to 4, 5, 6 unless otherwise specified in the .json config file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` is what google returns

Comment: Heh, I obviously cant use Google (I did try) - indeed that is the answer :) Thank you. If you want the points, post the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` results 1,2,3 after deserialization, not the 4,5,6, as OP wants

Comment: *not the 4,5,6, as OP wants* ... I'm pretty sure that is **not true** as: *I'd like MyProperty2 to DEFAULT to 4, 5, 6 **unless otherwise specified** in the .json config file*

Comment: the only problem it would be `{  "MyProperty2": null }` in json(but then it's still *specified in the json*)

Comment: @Selvin: Appreciated. If the configurer is chump enough to define that in the .json config... their bad :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from one of the comments above, and combined with my obsessive compulsive requirement to not leave a question with an unaccepted answer, herewith:

Assuming that the variable `json` contains the content of the .json configuration file:

```
var cfg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
});
```

The key is the `ObjectCreationHandling` - the serializer setting `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` replaces the default rather than appending to it.

See more [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObjectCreationHandling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

try to solve everything inside the Config class:

```
public class Config
{
    public Config()
    {
        this.MyProperty2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
    }
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public List<int> MyProperty2 {
        get {
            return this.MyProperty2;
        } 
        set {
            if(this.MyProperty2.Count > 0)
            {
                this.MyProperty2.Clear();
                this.MyProperty2 = value;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me:
You may think that if a 'get' request is made it will set the default value. If a 'set' is done before the 'get' the property will only get the default value if the 'value' is null.

```
public class Config{
    public string MyProperty1{ get; set; }

    private List<int> myProperty2{ get; set; } ;
    public List<int> MyProperty2{ 
        get{
            if (myProperty2 == null)
                myProperty2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };

            return  myProperty2 ;
        } 
        set{
            myProperty2 = value;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is the long way to solve the problem :) However, as @Selvin noted above, using the JsonConvert setting `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` will solve the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert` of `Newtonsoft.Json`;

```
var setting = "{\"MyProperty1\": \"MyValue1\", \"MyProperty2\": [1, 2, 3]}";
var settingConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(setting);
```

And Config Class

```
public class Config
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(DefaultArrayConverter))]
    public List<int> MyProperty2 { get; set; } = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
}
```

Here I wrote a customer JsonConverter.

```
public class DefaultArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It is working fine but I am not exactly sure why `MyProperty2` has 6 values in your implementation.